# pdflatex renders document with all dashes in bold

Tags: pdftex, okular

I have proceeded a new installation of LaTeX (in a new system: Ubuntu 12.04), I was installing from tug.org. Previously I was using TeX Live installed by apititude, on Ubuntu 10.04.

I'm using Kile as editor, xdvi for dvi, Okular for pdf files.

In all my LaTeX files I was using encoding utf-8x (`\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`). In the new installation I was getting error message from `inputenc`: *utf-8x definition not found*. I've found that utf-8x is outdated, so I've changed to utf-8 and it worked.

When I run command `latex (view with xdvi)` the dashes are normal. When I run `pdflatex`, the dashes are in bold and whole text doesn't look nice. Here is the screenshot of a part of the document:

[image: screenshot]

UPDATE

```
</home/mariajulia/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecbx2488.600pk>         </home/mariajulia/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ectt1000.600pk> </home/mariajulia/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecrm0800.600pk> </home/mariajulia/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecrm0600.600pk> </home/mariajulia/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecrm0700.600pk> </home/mariajulia/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecbx1000.600pk> </home/mariajulia/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecti1000.600pk> </home/mariajulia/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecrm1000.600pk> </home/mariajulia/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecbx1440.600pk></usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
```

UPDATE

I've removed whole installation and proceded a new one, this time without unchecking anything. The log file contains two

```
Installing [1518/2569, time/total: 02:08:52/03:24:08]: minted [360k] TLDownload::get_file: response error:    400 FTP return code 000 permanent server connection set up, but downloading did not succeed!Retrying with wget.
Installing [1519/2569, time/total: 02:09:59/03:25:50]: minutes [273k]
```

Second time was after `active-conf [327k]` package, the next one is `actuarialangle [3k]`

Comment: It looks like you haven't installed the CM-Super fonts, so with the T1 font encoding (that's used for Polish) the fonts are bitmap. I suggest to do a full install.

Comment: @egreg I've done almost full install. The only thing I've uncheck was language packages that I don't need. I didn't uncheck Polish :)

Comment: @egreg I've just tried to update cm-super package. Terminal output: Executing action update cm-super

tlmgr: no updates available
Completed.

Comment: Can you try adding `\usepackage{lmodern}` to your preamble?

Comment: @egreg I've tried, and it works :). Although I don't understand why previously I didn't need it, I'm happy it's working now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: With `tlmgr` you should do `sudo tlmgr install cm-super`

Comment: @egreg But cm-super is up to date. And the problem was solved by adding \usepackage{lmodern} line. So you've already resolved my problem, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Can you add the final part of the `.log` file when you don't load `lmodern`? Just above `Output written on...` there is the list of the fonts used in the document.

Comment: The final part of the log shows that the CM-Super fonts are *not* installed.